# Numerical values of coupling constants in the SM

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, renormalization, physical-constants

Where can one find the numerical values of the various coupling constants (mainly $\lambda$, $g$, $g'$, $g_S$ and $h_t$) in the SM at a fixed renormalization scale $\mu$? They don't all have to be evaluated on the same value of the RG scale of course, I just need them for a numerical simulation. I've tried using the PDG tables but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the papers [*Investigating the near-criticality of the Higgs boson*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3536), p.6 and p.13, and [*On the gauge dependence of the Standard Model vacuum instability scale*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7450), p.12, the numerical values of the coupling constants in the $\overline{MS}$ renormalization scheme, computed at 2-loop accuracy, are the following:

$\lambda(\mu=M_t)= 0.12710\\
h_t(M_t) = 0.93697\\
g_S (M_t ) = 1.1666\\
g(M_t ) = 0.6483\\
g'(M_t ) = 0.3587
$